# Login with existing file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a basic login system wherein it saves the user's inputted username and password to a file and the user can login by the system reading the file and check if there are existing username and password. But when I close the program and run it again, it overwrites the existing texts in the file. I need the program to run wherein it doesn't delete the texts inside a file and rather continues to a point where it stopped. Also, I don't know how to check if the file is already existing.

```
int main(){
    string username;
    string password;
    string xuser;
    string xpass;
    ifstream xFile;
    ofstream cFile;
    xFile.open("login.txt");
    cFile.open("login.txt");
    // if(there are existing username and password in the file){
    //     the file will not be overwritten and continues off to a new line
    // }
    cout<<"Register"<<endl;
    cout<<"Username: ";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"Password: ";
    cin>>password;
    cFile << username << endl;
    cFile << password << endl;
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"Login"<<endl;
    cout<<"Username: ";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"Password: ";
    cin>>password;
    xFile >> xuser;
    xFile >> xpass;
    if(username == xuser){
        cout<<"Username correct"<<endl;
    }
    if(password == xpass){
        cout<<"Password correct"<<endl;
    }

xFile.close();
cFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you obviously need to check if the files exists.

Comment: Please reformulate. It's not quite clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also, somehow offtopic, please don't use system("CLS") anymore. It's very unsecure.

Comment: Specify mode by passing `std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app` to [std::ofstream::open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/).

Comment: Maybe don't open the file for reading until after you close the file for writing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to programming and I am currently taking elementary programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

When you use [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) to write to a file, it's default behavior is to overwrite any existing content.

**Solution**

Tell `std::ofstream` that you want it to append to the file instead of overwrite everything by passing `std::ofstream::app` when you open the stream.

Replace the following line:

`cFile.open("login.txt");`

with

`cFile.open("login.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);`

**Note**

You must pass `std::fstream::out` together with `std::fstream::app`. This is because passing your own mode will overwrite any default mode including `std::fstream::out`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not quite sure how to use it. Is it before opening the file `cFile.app;
cFile.open("login.txt");` ?

Comment: Ohh, never mind my previous comment. Thank you, it helped!